# Using echo in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

I'd like to make a sciript, that displays this text:

> 

````````````
                                                                                `---            
     :///////:::-`         .///-             :///`    `///////////////-         dMMM+           
    +MMMMMMMMMMMMMmy:      .NMMM+           oMMMd`    dMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMd         hMMM/           
    +MMMy:::::/+yNMMMy      -NMMM/         +MMMd`     mMMM+:::::::::::-         hMMM/           
    +MMMs        `mMMM+      .mMMM/       +MMMd`      mMMM.                     hMMM/           
    +MMMs         oMMMy       .mMMM/     +MMMh`       mMMM.                     yMMM:           
    +MMMs         hMMM+        .mMMM:   /MMMh`        mMMM.                     yMMM:           
    +MMMs       -hMMMo          .mMMN- :MMMh`         mMMM.                     sMMM:           
    +MMMNmmmmmmMMMMy.            .mMMN/NMMh           mMMMMMMMMMMMMMN`          oMMM.           
    +MMMmhhhhhdmNMMMMh/           .mMMMMMh            mMMMyyyyyyyyyys`          oMMM.           
    +MMMs        `/mMMMy           .mMMMh             mMMM.                     oMMM.           
    +MMMs          `mMMM+           yMMM/             mMMM.                     +MMM`           
    +MMMs           yMMMs           yMMM/             mMMM.                     -yyy            
    +MMMs          `mMMM/           yMMM/             mMMM.                                     
    +MMMs       `-oNMMMo            yMMM/             mMMM.```````````          ymmd/           
    +MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNy-             yMMM/             mMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN        .MMMMd           
    .syyyyyyyyyyso/-                /yhy-             /yyyyyyyyyyyyyyys         ohhh:
````````````

When I use echo, cmd displays this (with different strings between apostrophes) line many times:

```
'`---' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How to make it just display string I want?

Comment: Can you provide the actual script you are using?

Comment: Show us your batch file.  ***Show Code***!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you did not do the `echo` per line. Also note, should any of your lines contain special characters such as `>` `<` or `|` `&` `^`. You will require escaping them.

````````````
@echo off & cls
echo                                                                                `---
echo     :///////:::-`         .///-             :///`    `///////////////-         dMMM+
echo    +MMMMMMMMMMMMMmy:      .NMMM+           oMMMd`    dMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMd         hMMM/
echo    +MMMy:::::/+yNMMMy      -NMMM/         +MMMd`     mMMM+:::::::::::-         hMMM/
echo    +MMMs        `mMMM+      .mMMM/       +MMMd`      mMMM.                     hMMM/
echo    +MMMs         oMMMy       .mMMM/     +MMMh`       mMMM.                     yMMM:
echo    +MMMs         hMMM+        .mMMM:   /MMMh`        mMMM.                     yMMM:
echo    +MMMs       -hMMMo          .mMMN- :MMMh`         mMMM.                     sMMM:
echo    +MMMNmmmmmmMMMMy.            .mMMN/NMMh           mMMMMMMMMMMMMMN`          oMMM.
echo    +MMMmhhhhhdmNMMMMh/           .mMMMMMh            mMMMyyyyyyyyyys`          oMMM.
echo    +MMMs        `/mMMMy           .mMMMh             mMMM.                     oMMM.
echo    +MMMs          `mMMM+           yMMM/             mMMM.                     +MMM`
echo    +MMMs           yMMMs           yMMM/             mMMM.                     -yyy
echo    +MMMs          `mMMM/           yMMM/             mMMM.
echo    +MMMs       `-oNMMMo            yMMM/             mMMM.```````````          ymmd/
echo    +MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNy-             yMMM/             mMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMN        .MMMMd
echo    .syyyyyyyyyyso/-                /yhy-             /yyyyyyyyyyyyyyys         ohhh:
````````````